# `top` – Any Shortcut for Showing Only Current User’s Processes?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, top

When I run `top`, after having looked at all currently running processes, I often want to filter down to only my own processes. So I hit <kbd>u</kbd>, type my user name and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

However, in our company, Unix user names follow the `firstname_lastname` pattern which can become cumbersome to type when you have a long name. So I wonder if there is any shortcut to interactively only showing the current user’s processes? (similar to simply hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> after hitting <kbd>u</kbd> to see all processes again)

Comment: Not interactive, but you could define `alias utop='top -u first_last'` and run `utop` in a different terminal. Or, just keep a scratchpad vi open with all those long strings you keep mistyqing, so you can just paste them whenever.

Comment: you can use `top -u ` and add a variable that outputs the logged user. something like `top -u $(whoami)`and that should output the processes of the user that is logged in the session.

Comment: @BANJOSA: the question aksed about doing it in top interactive mode.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes,

you can use the user id instead. This works both in interactive mode and using command line options

```bsh
man top
-u | -U  :User-filter-mode as:  -u | -U number or name
            Display  only  processes  with a user id or user name matching that given.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t have the same user ID on all hosts that I connect to. But this may at least be better than using a user name on some hosts, so +1, thanks! I still wonder if there is no better solution, without having to memorize user IDs …

Comment: Just run `top -u $UID` or create an alias for it. Your shell knows your UID.